# Best quick alternative compiler/IDE to Turbo C that supports audio and graphics

Tags: c, audio, graphics, ide, turbo-c

I am making a small **2d GAME PACK** as my University project. I am using Turboc 3.0 as the compiler. I am at a stage where I need better graphics and sound. Ive spent days looking for a workaround on the net and by myself too including audio and better graphics.Can you please tell me **which Ide can be learnt quickly**, as time is a constraint here?

Comment: I'm unaware of Turbo C, but what do audio and graphics have to do with an IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turbo C is just an IDE + compiler for the C programming language. C does not have any audio or graphics capabilities on its own, which means that you will not find a C IDE that readily incorporates such functionality. What you need is a [*library*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) with a C API that will allow you to do such things.

IIRC Turbo C did come with a rudimentary graphics library for DOS, but I do not believe that there was any support for audio. Unfortunately (or not) Turbo C is pretty much obsolete these days. Most programs written in it would have issues on modern operating systems and handling audio and graphics on DOS essentially means talking straight to the hardware - definitely not something trivial.

If you are after a *modern* audio/graphics library, [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is a popular choice for 2D games and, from my experience, rather easy to work with. You will probably need to couple it with a more modern programming environment though - I doubt Turbo C will cut it. You might want to have a look at one or more of the following for a compiler and/or IDE that will be fully functional on modern systems.:

- [Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)
- [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

  Warning: this IDE has not been updated for quite some time. I have used it successfully in the past, but I would not recommend investing time and resources on it at this point.
- [Mingw32](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/), downloadable [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

  Warning: Eclipse is mostly targeted to professional developers. It is *very* powerful, but it can occasionally be rather confusing to use. While it will save you a lot of time in the long run, it may not be perfectly suitable for someone that needs to get work done right here, right now.
- [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express)

Comment: I would not recommend Dev-C++.

Comment: @Bart: It *is* outdated, true, but considering that the OP is using *Turbo C* straight from 1991, I doubt they'll mind :-)

Comment: Haha, up to a point that's true. But Dev-C++ is so outdated, buggy and problematic (with questions being asked here as a result of it ,the answer to which is, "don't use it") that I think it's better removed. There seem to be [some new independent developments](http://orwellengine.blogspot.com/), but I'm not sure how good they are (haven't tried personally).

Comment: woah, thanks guys, that cleared a lot of things for me now. 1 more thing, for graphics i am thinking opengl cause its the easiest and cross platform. but for ide, i want one such that its cross platform and not outdated so that i dont have to face any updations problems again like in turbo c ... is code blocks suitable in that way? because even if it has all of the latest features as displayed here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments) its last stable release is 20 months ago... kindly suggest any other
ides/ compilers.

Comment: @thkala I thought of using OPENGL. But what about the sound. Does SDL support audio functions?

Comment: @JASMEETBHATIA: [sure it does...](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html)